# "Watched any" vs "saw any" in a sentence

Tags: usage

**Have you watched any new movies?**

Is this the correct way to ask? Or is it better to ask **Saw any new movies?**

Comment: You can certainly ask "Have you watched any new movies?", but rather than "Saw any new movies?", we'd typically phrase it as "[Have you] *seen* any good movies?". As I learned on this site, the intentional omission of words which are so predicable that your interlocutor can understand what was omitted simply from context is known as "conversational deletion". Anyway, I think you'd get better and easier to understand answers if you instead asked this (and any follow-up) answers on our sister site dedicated to people trying to learn English as a foreign language, [ELL.se].

Comment: @DanBron thanks, I wanted to know which is the better usage? I have heard people using both. Are you saying *saw any new movie?* is wrong?

Comment: To most native speakers, asking "Saw any good movies?" would mark you as a foreigner (which is to say it is unidiomatic: it's harder than you think to definitively state whether a particular utterance is "wrong" or not, and it gets harder the more you learn about English, as I'm discovering, so I am starting to shy from that label). As to which is better: they're simply options. Use whichever suits you, or whichever you hear more often from (native speaking) people around you. It's worth noting that *watch* connotes more engagement, is more active, than *see* (like listen vs hear).

Comment: @DanBron Thanks for the answer. You could post it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, note that *Saw any good movies* is unidiomatic, if not wrong entirely—the question is *have you seen*, not *have you saw*.

I feel I most commonly hear *[Have you] seen any good movies recently?*

*[Have you] watched any good movies* is definitely acceptable and idiomatic, just somewhat less common in my experience.

Side note for reference, I'd expect:

> Let's watch a movie [at home]
>   Let's go see a movie [in the theater]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. *Seen any new movies?* looks like the best option.