# Difference between "see a movie" and "watch a movie"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm learning English now so I need some helps to build on my English.

My question is if I can use the word "see" in "see a movie", because I understand that the correct word to "see a movie or to see tv" is WATCH but I heard some people saying "see a movie" not "watch a movie".

I am so confused really. It's too basic I know but help me please, thanks.

Comment: [Related question - "Do you watch or see a movie?"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6183/48335)

Comment: [Also related - "watched vs saw any"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89511/watched-any-vs-saw-any-in-a-sentence/89512#89512)

Comment: @J.R.♦: I think it's a duplicate. The only significant usage difference (we tend to *watch* stuff on small home/handheld screens, and *see* movies at the cinema) is covered by an answer there.

Comment: @Fumble - That question only asks about movies, not TV. If anything, I'd be inclined to merge that one with this one. I think this is the better question.

Comment: @J.R. - You are correct, but I think that the third sentence in the example cleared that point.

Comment: @xxxxxx - Perhaps it does, but I'm still inclined to keep the better question open. I think that's better for the site in the long run, and should be considered before voting to close something as a "duplicate question." Note the verbiage in the close reason: _This question has been asked before_.

Comment: There's also [“Watch movie X” vs “see movie X”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/53693/), which I answered myself. But arguably they (and doubtless others) could all be closed as duplicates of [What is the difference between “look”, “see”, and “watch”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/444/)

Comment: Google Books has just 8 instances of [*(we went) to the movie theater and **watched** (some film)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22to+the+movie+theater+and+watched%22), but it thinks there are 191 instances of the same with ***saw***. The figures for *...to the cinema and **watched/saw...*** are 628/1310 (a less marked preference - but still significant, I think).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Thanks! That "“Watch movie X” vs “see movie X” is the question I was looking for when I left my initial comment. I couldn't find it for some reason.

Comment: @J.R.♦: There are some subtleties that have probably never been explicitly flagged up in the specific context of *movies*. It occurs to me that if someone asked me whether I like movie X, the response *I don't know, I haven't **watched** it*, could more strongly imply I have actually *got* the movie (on DVD, available through my chosen "movies-R-us" provider, or whatever). But it's the same *passive/active* distinction as ***heard / listened to,*** all of which is covered very well [here.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/445/126)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - actually the question could be: Did you see the movie X ? No, I haven't watched it yet.

Comment: @xxxxxx: Sure. Or it could be *Did you watch X? No, I haven't seen it yet.*  Both perfectly valid, but there's at least a *tendency* to favour ***watched*** for the reply if you have actually been in a position to do so (but have *chosen* not to, an active rather than passive choice). By the same token you might be more inclined to use ***watch*** rather than ***see*** in the original question if you know the other guy has the DVD or some other easy way to play it. It's more *Did you get around to watching it?* rather than *Did you get around to seeing it?*

Answer (score 1):

***[Watch](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/look-at-see-or-watch)*** is similar to look at, but ***it usually means that we look at something for a period of time, especially something that is changing or moving:***

> - *We watch television every evening.*
> - *I like to sit at the window to watch what’s happening in the garden.*

***Warning:***

> ***We use see, not watch, when we talk about being at sports matches or public performances, such as films, theatre and dramas. However, we watch the television:***
>
> - *We saw a wonderful new film last night. You’ll have to go and see it while it’s in the cinema.*
> - ***Not***: *We watched… You’ll have to go and watch* …

(Cambridge Dictionary)

***Watch a Movie vs See a Movie***:

> - We watched a movie yesterday.
>     *This would imply we watched a movie at home (TV/DVD...)*
> - We saw a movie yesterday.
>     *This would imply that we did so by going to a movie theater*.
> - We can also explicitly say that we went to the movie theater and watched Ice Age.

Comment: I think both _watched_ and _saw_ can be used for your last example: _We went the theater yesterday and saw Wicked._

Comment: @J.R. is correct with his example. Also note that you can use "see" when describing a particular show (even if watched at home). "I finally saw the last episode of Breaking Bad"

Comment: @J.R. - I am referring to your comment here. The second and the third sentences say that see and watch can be used in that context.

Comment: @xxxxx - Okay, I see that now. I must have gotten confused for some reason. (By the way, I had already upvoted this answer; it's a good one.)